# Pushover cURL-code gives error

Tags: php, curl

I have this code:

```
    curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            "token" => "XXX",
            "user" => "XXX",
            "message" => $msg,
    ),
    CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => true,
    ));
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

But is gives me this error:

```
Array keys must be CURLOPT constants or equivalent integer values in /etc/noiphp/run.php on line 73
```

Any ideas?

cURL-version info:

```
curl 7.29.0 (mips-openwrt-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1h zlib/1.2.7
Protocols: file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` is only supported on `PHP >= 5.5.0`, remove that option and you should be good to go, also, it wasn't an `error`, just a `warning`.

```
curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            "token" => "XXX",
            "user" => "XXX",
            "message" => $msg,
    )
    ));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

---

```
CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD
```

> `TRUE` to disable support for the @ prefix for uploading files in
>   `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, which means that values starting with @ can be
>   safely passed as fields. [CURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) may be used for uploads instead.
>   Added on PHP 5.5.0 with `FALSE` as the default value. PHP 5.6.0 changes the
>   default value to `TRUE`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php